# How can I limit the md5() function PHP to generate 8 random caharacters and numbers?

Tags: php

How can I limit the following code to generate 8 mixed characters and number in the code below.

Here is the PHP code.

```
md5(uniqid(rand(1,6)));
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A md5 hash is always 32 characters long ; that's what an [md5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5) is.

But you could choose to use only 8 characters from the string returned by the [`md5()`](http://fr.php.net/md5) function, with the [**`substr`**](http://fr.php.net/substr) function.

For example, to keep only the first eight characters, you could use something like this :

```
echo substr(md5(uniqid(rand(1,6))), 0, 8);
```

And it would get you something like this :

```
4651da2b
```

Comment: An md5 is 128-bit long (16 bytes). What's 32 bytes long is the hexadecimal representation, since each byte now encodes only a nibble.